# Does Visual studio 2017 have syntax checking for C?

Tags: c, visual-c++, syntax-checking

I would like to get syntax checking for my .c in Visual Studio 2017, but it seems I only get it if my source file is named  source.cpp, not source.c

Is it possible to turn it on?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why this is tagged for python if it's a C lang question?

Comment: my bad. trying to fix it

Comment: What's "syntax checking", compiling? VS does not support standard C so I doubt it will have correct syntax highlighting, if that's what you mean.

Comment: This should work by default. My VS 2017 gives correct syntax highlighting for both `.cpp` and `.c` files. Contrary to popular opinion, MSVC has (somewhat) proper support for C89.

Comment: Is there a way to turn that on/off? I want to flip the switch, see if i can get it to work.

Comment: @ComicSansMS That's what I wrote: "does not support standard C". C90 was withdrawn NINETEEN YEARS ago.

Comment: @ComicSansMS *MSVC has (somewhat) proper support for C89* That's stating that MSVC support for a twenty-year-old standard isn't actually proper...

Comment: @AndrewHenle Which is still more than enough if all you're asking for is basic syntax checking. The way I read the question, Op is not getting any syntax highlighting at all when renaming the file to `.c`, which should not happen.

Comment: Ya I get the colours for the key words but no ~~~~~~ under the wrong spellings like prin("Hello World!") instead of printf("Hello World!")

Comment: Hmya, prin("asdf') is valid C syntax.  It produces a linker error, but the IntelliSense parser does not worry about linking.  Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to encourage them to squiggle the /W3 warning.

Comment: @Lundin Well, 18 years and (almost) 5 months ago for C90 TC2.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install the complete part of C/C++ desktop develop tool.

My one works fine:[image]

[image]

Comment: ok ,i'll try to install everything in that category once I get to a better connection. Thanks!

Comment: no, let me try that out first, I am still hours away from a good connection.

Comment: No, i installed everything under the C++ category and I still don't have wavelines. Maybe it's because the way I added the .c files?  I right click on "source files" to "add" "new item",    select .cpp and then backspace the "pp" to get .c, and then click "add".   did i do that wrong?  thanks

Comment: Maybe also worth noting is I installed VS code and messed around with it. Could something go wrong there interfere with the Visual Studio 2017 Community?

Comment: I found the proper name for what I am looking for:  "Error squiggles"  I have created hello world using both .c and .cpp, but the .c version won't show "Error squiggles" even if i put down printfffff("hello");

Comment: @Brad So what do you mean by "is I installed VS code and messed around with it"?? Have you tried to install everything in??

Comment: yes, I wasn't sure what was what so i installed a lot of things but dont know how to use them. Apparently by default it compiles by using gcc and i dont have gcc.

Comment: Well you are saying you play with it and do something strange that makes the default compiler as gcc??

Comment: I don't know, but could any change made to VS code affect visual studio 2017?

Comment: I only can say this might be possible. So what I suggest is delete all unnecessary parts, only install the C/C++ desktop module first, then apply the repair option in VS installer, this will reset VS environment in some way. A more complete method is to reinstall VS with deleting of all personal settings, some software may help in cleaning the personal files after uninstall.